# How to simulate a circuit with LM2576 in it?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, simulation

*Background: I am software engineer with a limited knowledge of electronics. This is a n00b question.*

I want to design a circuit to step down DC voltage from about 24V to 12V. I have tried a [7812](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/78xx) linear voltage regulator but the chip heats up a lot even when attached to a heat sink.

I have now decided to use [LM2575](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2575-n.pdf) / [LM2576](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf) instead, since they are more power efficient than the 78xx series. But these chips require some more components (like diodes, registers, etc), before they can be used to supply power. I have figured out this circuit with the help of a handbook.

I now want to run a simulation of this before I dare to fry the chips (which, btw, were quite difficult to acquire locally).

What is the best way to simulate such a circuit using free/open-source tools? I tried searching for models for LM2575/LM2576 without success.

Comment: Have you heard of [the 3-transistor Black regulator](http://www.romanblack.com/smps/a04.htm) by Roman Black? It is an efficient 24 V to 12 V switching voltage regulator using common, easy-to-acquire parts.

Answer (score 4):

[TI's web site](http://www.ti.com/) also offers the Webench designer (brought over from the National web site when TI and National merged a while back). You can find it right on their home page and pick the "Power" tab.

The Webench designer helps you design a switching VR, shows you a schematic, BOM with suggested standard components and provides budgetary cost comparisons between competing designs. The tool also will simulate the design and show analysis results.

Comment: I had found the Webench a little too automatic. While it suggested a lot of designs, I couldn't find how to choose the specific ICs I wanted (LM257x). Will give it another try now.

Answer (score 3):

From the TI website for that part simply follow the links marked software and you will come across [Power Stage designer](http://www.ti.com/tool/powerstage-designer).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I can't see how this would be useful to me. I think it shows how to design a LM2575 rather than how to use it.